# Listview Header Wrap_content causing weird layout

Tags: android, listview, url, header, imageview

I have a listview with header attach using method addHeaderView(header);
same listview layout loading different data for same fragment depdens upon navigation drawer category.

header is having its own layout 
{

`**R.layout.header_layout**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.loopj.android.image.SmartImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
    android:src="@drawable/blankk" />`
}
Note: SmartImageView is library that loads image from url .

my problem is the, images that are loading into smartimageview (listview header) are not having fixed height so the layout for different fragment are different i.e not consistent .if i assign height as say 300dp images are getting crop.
plz help me to get get header of same height with images not getting crop.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove  android:baselineAlignBottom="true" from your smart imageview and use fix width. I hope it will works

Comment: According to you Fixed width means size in dp ?

Comment: images are getting crop after specifying in dp. i have to use android:scaleType="fitxy" but it is compressing image that is looks weird